# Tag "Select" in gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

How to correctly use tag `select` in gsp while passing to it `ArrayList<String>` ? I know how to use it this my own composed objects, for example:

```
<g:select name="tablePlacesAvailable" from="${tableInfo}" optionValue="${{it.placesInTableAmount}}" optionKey="placesInTableAmount" value=""/>
```

But how to use it with `built in` objects, like `String`?

Comment: can you post an example of what you're trying to do and what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `g:select` with a list of String

```
<g:select name="selection" from="${values}" />
```

Where `values` is a collection of Strings. My controller code is

```
class DemoController {
    def index() { 
        [values: ["This", "is", "a", "test"]]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tests and its results:
Controller:
Controller:

```
 def index() {
        def myList=['hello','world']
        def myMap=['h':'hello','w':'world']
        render view: 'index', model: [myList:myList,myMap:myMap]
    }
```

gsp:

```
<g:form name="test" >
 <g:select name="s1" from="${['lastUpdated', 'id']}" value="${sortby}"  />
 <g:select  name="s2" from="${['lastUpdated', 'id']}"
  optionKey="value" optionValue="value"  value="${sortby}"  />

 <g:select name="g"  from="${['90%':'90%','100%': '100%']}" 
 optionKey="key" optionValue="value" value="${params.g}" />

 <g:select name="g2"  from="${myList}" />

 <g:select name="g3"  from="${myMap}" />

 <g:select name="g4"  from="${myMap}" optionKey="key" optionValue="value"/>
 <g:select name="g5"  from="${myMap}" optionKey="key" optionValue="key"/>
 <g:select name="g6"  from="${myMap}" optionKey="value" optionValue="value"/>

<g:submitButton name="go" value="post"/>
</g:form>
```

Results:

```
[g:100%, s2:lastUpdated, s1:id, g2:world, g6:world, g5:w, g4:w, 
go:post, g3:w=world, action:index, format:null, controller:test]
```

As you can see a Arraylist with no optionKey optionValue works by default, in s2 I have also physically defined key value to be value and it still works